# BigQuery - concatenate all rows of column until particular value reached

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I want to concatenate all rows of a particular column until a certain value is reached.

So in my example, I want to concatenate 'PageType' column using ' > ' as separator until I reach a row where the string value is 'Checkout'

[User's page type journey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crcMx.jpg)

It should something look something like this:
Home > PLP > PDP > PLP > PDP > PLP > PDP > Checkout

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if there are multiple checkouts?

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann I wanted to report on the very first instance of checkout, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that you used Google Analytics data so I went and used the example data that is openly available. Instead of the unnecessary lateral cross-join with hits I wrote a subquery (containing another sub-query for the stop condition).

```sql
DECLARE stopPage DEFAULT '/basket.html';

SELECT
  fullvisitorid,
  visitstarttime,
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(page.pagePath, ' > ' ORDER BY time ASC) FROM UNNEST(hits) 
    WHERE type = 'PAGE' 
      AND time <= (select min(time) from unnest(hits) where page.pagePath=stopPage)) AS path
  #ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT ecommerceAction, page FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE  type = 'PAGE' ) AS hits
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` 
WHERE exists(SELECT 1 FROM unnest(hits) WHERE page.pagePath=stopPage)
LIMIT 1000
```

Since there is no page type I used a page path instead (I randomly chose /basket.html) - I think you can easily adjust the conditions.

You can run this query to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, filter before aggregating:

```
select visitid,
       string_agg(pagetype, '>' order by time) as checkout_path
from (select t.*,
             min(case when pagetype = 'Checkout' then time end) over (partition by visitid) as checkout_time
      from t
     ) t
where time <= checkout_time
group by visitid;
```

Comment: This was my script i initially used: 

SELECT
date,
fullVisitorId,
hits.time,
visitId,
visitNumber,
hits.hitNumber AS hitNumber,
PageType, 
FROM
  `table_name`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  geoNetwork.country = 'United Kingdom'
--  AND fullVisitorId = '7561186859875493195'
  AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
ORDER BY
  5 ASC, 6 ASC
LIMIT
  100000

Comment: @MoHawk . . . This answers the question that you have asked.  I don't know what your comment is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT visitId,
  SPLIT(path, ' > Checkout')[OFFSET(0)] || ' > Checkout' path
FROM (
  SELECT visitId, 
    STRING_AGG(PageType, ' > ' ORDER BY time) AS path
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY visitId
)
WHERE path LIKE '% > Checkout'
```

when applied to sample data as in your question - output is

```
Row visitId     path     
1   1597865846  Home > PLP > PDP > PLP > PDP > PLP > PDP > Checkout
```